# Remote Debug in Intellij is not connecting to wildfy application server(not locally running tomcat)

Tags: intellij-idea, server, wildfly, remote-debugging

I have an application server. I need to connect to that application server for debugging. I set the host and the port by adding a new remote connection.
[image]

But when I tried to connect it gives me the following error.

Error running 'Remote Debug': Unable to open debugger port (45gfc:3389): java.net.SocketException "Connection reset"

It would be really grateful if someone could help me with this.

Comment: Did you check if debugger port is open and not being used?

Comment: That looks like a very old version of Intellij Idea? You may battle to get it to work with newer Java versions.

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal debugger port is open. I checked that.

Comment: @SteveC but I have to use  this version. Cant I get connected to the application server using this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remote Debugging in IntelliJ Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733849/remote-debugging-in-intellij-tomcat)

Comment: @Andrey it didnt help me.