# set memory-size for tomcat running as service

Tags: linux, tomcat, amazon-ec2

As I´m running into memory-problems running my web-app I want to know how I can set the memory for tomcat-8 running on an AWS-linux as a service.

> GI-cat needs at least 1000MB free heap space to work properly. You
>   have 506MB free (total 1752MB). Increase the memory if possible, by
>   adding -Xmx1000m or more to the java arguments.

I´ve read [How do I increase memory on Tomcat 7 when running as a Windows Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984540/how-do-i-increase-memory-on-tomcat-7-when-running-as-a-windows-service) but it only handles windows-services, not linux.

I suppose I have to manipulate `catalina.sh`, don´t it but I´m unsure if this will effect the service when using `service tomcat8 restart`.

Answer (score 0):

### Non-persistent method

You can set the environment variable before you start your tomcat service:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xmx1000m"
```

And then start your service with:

```
service tomcat8 restart
```

**Side note:** this variable is only set until it gets unset/set by another process or your linux box restarts.

### Persistent method

To make this persistent, you want to modify `tomcat.conf` in `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/` and append/modify the environment variable with:

`CATALINA_OPTS="-Xmx1000m"`

**Ref:** https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/244197

**Updated #1:** Changed the response to better suit the author's needs.

Comment: But wouldn´t this affect all my other java-processes as well? I´m a bit reluctant on setting variables for the whole system, instead I just want to set it for that particular service. Nevertheless I´m looking for something more persistant so I won´t set it each time my host computer restarts.

Comment: That's a valid concern. JAVA_OPTS affects all jvm, if you only have one tomcat running. You could set CATALINA_OPTS instead.

Comment: To find out the difference between JAVA_OPTS and CATALINA_OPTS you can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222365/catalina-opts-vs-java-opts-what-is-the-difference

Comment: And to make it persistent, there's also this post http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/244197.