# Java Heap Size increased in catalina.bat but not reflecting same heap size when tomcat is restarted as Service

Tags: tomcat, windows-services

I have tomcat configured as windows service that is visible under services and have renamed the name of the service. I had requirement to increase jvm heap size ,I modified the catalina.bat file. Then I restarted the tomcat using bat, verified changes are reflecting and did shut down the server.

Next I restarted tomcat as windows service, I see my it is not reflecting the updated heap size.

I uninstalled the service and installed again but its not picking up updated heap size. Same works fine while restarting the server using bat fi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I increase memory on Tomcat 7 when running as a Windows Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984540/how-do-i-increase-memory-on-tomcat-7-when-running-as-a-windows-service)

Comment: FYI `catalina.bat` is not used when launching Tomcat as a Windows Service. Furthermore, you should set custom configuration in `setenv.bat` instead of modifying `catalina.bat`. See the duplicate question for how to modify the Windows Service.